# How to understand the usage of rep() in this case?

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-analysis, rep

There's a dataset `randomdat` contains 299 obs, two categorical variables, `var 9` contains the values like `With XYZ` and `Without XYZ`, `var8` contains values like `Group A`/ `Group B`/`Group C`, `var1` is a numerical variable.

Then there's a model:

`m7 <- lm(var3~var1+I(var1^2)+I(var1^3)+var9, data=randomdat)`

Check `summary(m7)`, it shows `Without XYZ` is always 34451.4 less than `With XYZ`.

```
> summary(m7)

Call:
lm(formula = var3 ~ var1 + I(var1^2) + I(var1^3) + var9, data = randomdat)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-391506  -75127    4799   77175  323856 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate    Std. Error t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     -162934.42035   18571.30251  -8.773 <0.0000000000000002 ***
var1              10927.87454     741.36511  14.740 <0.0000000000000002 ***
I(var1^2)          -180.82979      10.44006 -17.321 <0.0000000000000002 ***
I(var1^3)             0.99499       0.04223  23.562 <0.0000000000000002 ***
var9Without XYZ  -34451.43378   14570.55030  -2.364              0.0187 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 117500 on 294 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8642,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8624 
F-statistic: 467.9 on 4 and 294 DF,  p-value: < 0.00000000000000022
```

Then there're two predict models:

```
m7_predictwith <- predict(m7,list(var1=randomdat$var1, var9 = rep("With XYZ",299)))
m7_predictwout <- predict(m7,list(var1=randomdat$var1, var9 = rep("Without XYZ",299)))
```

If you plot them, you will see the the two lines are not overlapping.

```
ggplot(randomdat, aes(x = var1, y = var3)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour = var8, shape = var8)) + 
    geom_line(aes(x=randomdat$var1,y=m7_predictwith), color = 'red', lty = 2) + 
    geom_line(aes(x=randomdat$var1,y=m7_predictwout), color = 'black', lty = 3)
```

[image]

Now it comes with the question, how to understand `var9 = rep("With XYZ",299)` or `var9 = rep("Without XYZ",299)` in this case? Aren't them mean replace all the values in `var9` to `With XYZ` or `Without XYZ`? The `var1` is the same in `m7_predictwith` and `m7_predictwout`, the plot lines of them should be just one same line? Very confused about the syntax usage of `rep()` in this case.

Comment: Anyone?.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rep()` repeats values:

```r
> rep("With XYZ", 5)
[1] "With XYZ" "With XYZ" "With XYZ" "With XYZ" "With XYZ"
```

Here it's being used to created data sets that contain:

- The observed values of `var1`
- A fixed value of `var9`.

`var9` is a factor variable, and in the regression its estimated coefficient is -34451.43378. So if you predict one line with a fixed value for `var9` of `"With XYZ"`, and then another line with a fixed value of `"Without XYZ"`, the `"Without XYZ"` line will be shifted down by a constant value of 34451, creating parallel lines.

Comment: That's the part I don't understand, the coefficient -34451.43378 is for ```"Without XYZ"``` and ```"Without XYZ"```, right? Because ```var9With XYZ``` is the baseline, so it didn't show up at the ```summary(m7)```, right? Since the dataset ```randomdat``` contains 299 rows, ```var9 = rep("With XYZ",299)``` or ```var9 = rep("Without XYZ",299)```, it basicly repeats ```"With XYZ"``` or ```"Without XYZ"``` 299 times, can I just interpret it as all cells in column ```var9``` now is either ```"With XYZ"``` or ```"Without XYZ"```? In this case, the coefficient -34451.43378 seems doesn't make sence.

Comment: The coefficient means that, all other variables being equal, the difference between an observation "With XYZ" and "Without XYZ" is -34451.43378.

Comment: Yes, but aren't ```var9 = rep("With XYZ",299)``` or ```var9 = rep("Without XYZ",299)``` already replaced all values in ```var9``` in either ```"With XYZ"``` or ```"Without XYZ"```, because it repeats 299 times and there're only 299 obs in ```var9```? If all vaules are the same in ```var9```, how they`re parallel lines?

Comment: The prediction reflects the value of both `var1` and `var9`, and the values of `var1` change, so you get different predicted outcomes across `var1`. I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: ```var1``` is the same in ```m7_predictwith``` and ```m7_predictwout```, as you can see from above predict models